# Show single post only if written by current logged in author Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have found some code which restricts a feed of posts to the current logged in author below, and it works great. Now I am looking for a way to apply the same restriction to a single post. What would I adjust in the code so it would work on single.php? If I use this code it as it is right now, it generates a feed rather than a single post.

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()):
        global $current_user;
        wp_get_current_user();
        $author_query = array('author' => $current_user->ID);
        $author_posts = new WP_Query($author_query);
        while($author_posts->have_posts()) : $author_posts->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Just to confirm: When you say "work on a single post", do you mean that you only want it to return one post? If so, which one, e.g. the most recent?

Comment: I'm using it on single.php so I would want it to generate whichever post I had clicked on in the feed. It should do what the code below does, but with the current logged in author restriction:
`<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the post id into `WP_Query` along with the author, e.g.

```
$args = array('author' => $current_user->ID,
              'p' => get_the_ID() );
$author_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

However this seems like you are doing extra work that you don't need - you are already on the post page so the loop is already set up to show the post details.

I assume what you are trying to do is check if it is the logged-in user's own post and only display it if it is. In that case, all you need to do is this:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if (is_user_logged_in() && $current_user->ID == $post->post_author)  {
    /* the user is logged in and the current logged-in user is the post author */      
    /* Show the post here....*/
}
else{

    /* Author is not the logged in user!
       Do whatever you want in this case...*/
}
```

Reference: [Check if The Current User is The Post Author in WordPress](http://wpcodesnippet.com/check-if-current-user-is-post-author/) (Updated to replace deprecated function)

Comment: Wonderful, thankyou! needed to set it up without the curly brackets so in the end this was the final code I used:

`<?php global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo();
    if (is_user_logged_in() && $current_user->ID == $post->post_author) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>`

Comment: @siaeva Glad to help! Yes I come from a software engineering background so `{`...`}` is more natural to me than the `if:`...`endif` / `while:`...`endwhile` equivalents, but they work the same way :)